# How can we match(") as pattern with python regular expression

Tags: python-2.7

How can we match `"`as pattern with python regular expressions?
I just want to parse URL from the string

`---href=http:"xyz.html"---`

I tried  `re.findall("href=(.+.html)",string)`

but it gives `http:"xyz.html`
but what I want is `http:xyz.html`.

Can some one help here.

I am on python v 2.7

Comment: I fixed some of your formatting, but in order to make sense you'll have to put a little more work into your post. Also, your regular expression will match `'https:"xyz.html'` and not what you say it does.

Comment: Yes timgeb,I made the required changes.Can you solve the problem ?